# How can I reverse an AnimationController by clicking on the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button, flutter-animation

I am doing something similar to this guide:
[bottom app bar with fab](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/2018-09-13-bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/)

I want the animation to close on clicking anywhere other than the FloatingActionButton.

The only solution I could think of is wrapping the Scaffold body with a GestureDetector and reversing the animation on click.
The problem is, the screen is a CustomScrollView with buttons inside it, so this solution won't work (because scrolling or clicking on those buttons won't reverse the animation).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the scaffold body in a `GestureDetector` will work fine. Just set its hit-test behavior to [`HitTestBehavior.opaque`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/behavior.html) and wrap its child in an [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) to make doubly sure the scroll view and buttons don't override the tap behavior.

```dart
Scaffold(
  ...
  body: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () => print('tapped'),
    child: IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: true,
      child: ...
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```